# Git merge 2 branch without conflict

Tags: git, github, merge

As below figure showed, tree on left side is from Origin, I am wondering how to ignore commit a1 on Branch a and then fast-forward Branch a to Branch b commit b2 without any conflict.
The below is my option so far:

1. git revert a1 to init commit --> git checkout b2 on Branch b --> git merge a: This will cause large conflict. (I don't know why so far)
2. git reset --hard a1 to init --> git push --force --> git pull --> git checkout b2 on Branch b --> git merge a : I am not sure if this process will change the commit history on Branch b

If there is any good way to accomplish the target, please let me know, thanks.
[image]

Comment: That looks like you want to _move_ the branch (branches in git are just pointers to commit): `git branch -f brancha branchb` (the only thing is that you must not have checked out brancha when you run it).

Answer (score 1):

Branches are just commit names. So simply move the name `branchA` to the commit where you want it.

```
git fetch
git switch branchA
git reset --hard SHA-of-commitB2
git push --force origin branchA
```

Comment: This works, finally I did the same thing as your post:
git switch branchA
git reset --hard SHA-of-init commit
git push --force
git merge b --ff-only SHA-of commitB2
git push

However, would you please tell me why conflict will happen in option1, after revert to init commit, barnchA have the same status with BranchB, it should have no conflict by merging 2 branch, thanks.

Comment: I answered the question you asked. If you have a different question click Ask Question and ask it. If you don't understand what merge and revert do, I have written a helpful article on the topic.